# Python: User Input to create folders

Tags: python

I am trying to use the following working code and convert it to user input.

```
rp = ‘folder_path’

list = [‘test’, ‘test2’]

for i in list:
    path = os.path.join(rp, i)
    os.mkdir(path)
```

Essentially, this will make a folder named “test” and “test2” in the folder_path.

Is there a way to make the list from user input?

I have tried the following (manipulating it a bunch) with no luck.

```
rp = ‘folder_path’

list = []

foldName = int(input(“Folder Name? “))

for i in range(0, foldName):
    path = os.path.join(rp, list)
    os.mkdir(path)
```

Comment: Are you just going to have the user type a single folder?  If so, then you shouldn't have a loop at all.  Just `os.path.join(rp, foldName)`.  If you want the user to enter a series of folder names, then you have to decide how they will be separated.  Commas?  Spaces?

Comment: Why are you converting the `foldName` input to an `int`?

Comment: Based on your approach you need first to ask for the number of folders to create and then for names of each individual folder.

Comment: @TimRoberts it would be for an X amount of folders, so it could be 1 or more.

Comment: @hackerboi then you should ask: `How many folders do you want to create?` 

Comment: Then YOU have to decide what the separator will be.  Do you want them to type "one two three"?  Then you would use `foldName.split()`. Do you want them to type "one,two,three"?  Then you would use `foldName.split(',')`.  It's up to YOU to translate the string they type into a set of folder names, based on YOUR rule for input.

Comment: You have the wrong type of quotes in your code. Remember to turn off "smart quotes" when writing or copying code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import os

root = 'root path'
x = input("Enter names of folders : ") ## test,test3
list = x.split(",") ## specific separator 
for i in list:
    path = os.path.join(root, i)
    os.mkdir(path)
```

Quick and dirty - try this .. also not sure what the int conversion is about

Comment: This is not a good solution, what happens if the user missed the commas, he has no idea that he should insert one to separate it

Comment: Another problem: what happens if the user insert characters which aren’t allowed to use for folder naming etc.

Comment: @droebi, great points. I wasn't trying to provide a bullet proof solution, just some assistance. Think more mvp..Constraints and filters can be added based on the requirements as needed ..

Comment: I guess that is true; however, I will be the only one inserting the information. But a fair point nonetheless. I will continue to work on it to modify it. Actually, I’ve been playing around with it to do that. I appreciate everyone’s advice and input!